# Error "Unable to resolve host <url>: No address associated with hostname" for application with Internet permission

Tags: android, wifi, android-5.0-lollipop

I am developing an android application on Android L (5.0.1). I have internet permission in my manifest as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I am receiving the following error:
`Unable to resolve host <url>: No address associated with hostname`
while running my application.

Restarting the Wifi on the phone while the application is open fixes the issue for that session. That means the URL is working fine.
Doing this each time while testing the application is time consuming.
This is also unacceptable in production.

Could not find any similar issues online. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your `website URL:`

Comment: Hi. As mentioned in the question, on restarting the wifi when the application is open, I'm able to connect to the URL. Hence the URL should be working fine.

Comment: That means your device does not recognized WiFi after restart.

Comment: Disconnected applications throw same error. I was facing this yesterday, and argued with back end that url is invalid until realized (quite foolishly) that internet was disconnected.

Comment: @Kay Even when the application is throwing this error, other apps are able to connect to internet. Can a single application be disconnected even with internet permission? If so, whats could be the reason?

Comment: Can you post the url ?

Comment: @DavidJhons The URL is http://www.findauto.in/registerDriverApp.php. I'm doing an HttpPost to that URL.

Comment: Also can you put the relevant code as this is a post request .

Comment: @DavidJhons issue got resolved after device restart. Thanks for helping out! :)

Comment: Can not ping to the shared url. Error: Could not find host. Though findauto.in pings just fine.

Comment: You also have a warning in the php file : Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/easyauto/public_html/registerDriverApp.php on line 14

Comment: @Kay server code is under development. Not yet handling exceptions. Requires POST params to work correctly.

Comment: You can debug by calling the service from any rest client other than Android. If everything is fine, try working app on 3G since it would look like your wifi is busted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by restarting my device.

Now my application is able to send request to the server without having to restart device wifi. Not sure what caused the issue though.

Thanks for the quick support guys. :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure You have concerned over followings ,

1. Always you are passing a valid url
2. You have connected to stable internet source.

Comment: Restarting WiFi fixes the issue. Hence this shouldn't be an issue with the URL. Also, the internet connection is pretty stable since I am not having any connectivity issues on other apps or on laptop.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I have connection timeout and read timeout setup. Why is that it throws UnknowHostExcpetion and not SocketTimeoutException after the timeout period ?